# jquerymobile 1.4.2 - Animate collapsible

Tags: jquery-mobile, animation, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I want to animate a collapsible set in jquery mobile 1.4.2. Unfortunately I haven't found anything. All animated scripts use version 1.3.2 oder 1.4.0.

I'm still a newbie and don't know if I just can switch down to 1.4.0 or 1.3.2 keeping my design?

What can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

Instead of a collapsibleset, use a wrapper div with the `class="ui-collapsible-set"`, this gives you the collapsible set styling, but then allows you to implement the logic:

```
<div class="ui-collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" class="animateMe">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 1</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" class="animateMe">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 2</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" class="animateMe">
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible content for section 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added a class of animateMe to each collapsible for convenience in adding a handler:

```
$(".animateMe .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").on("click", function (e) { 
    var current = $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible");             
    if (current.hasClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed")) {
        //collapse all others and then expand this one
        $(".ui-collapsible").not(".ui-collapsible-collapsed").find(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").click();
        $(".ui-collapsible-content", current).slideDown(300);
    } else {
        $(".ui-collapsible-content", current).slideUp(300);
    }
});
```

This code is a click handler on each collapsible header. It checks to see if the clicked collapsible is currently expanded or collapsed. If it is expanded, we simply collapse it with the slideUp animation. If it is collapsed, we first collapse any expanded items and then expand this one with the slideDown animation.

If you want to allow multiple items to be expanded at the same time, just remove this line:

```
$(".ui-collapsible").not(".ui-collapsible-collapsed").find(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").click();
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Js7C8/1/)**

Comment: Wonderfull! Works great!

Comment: Tried several examples but non of them worked, this one is working, and you added the fiddle, nice!

Comment: @Fede. I'm glad you found it helpful.

Comment: This would be great if it animated initially on an expanded set that used `data-collapsed="false"` and was expanded initially.  For some reason, the  first collapse of the collapsible set does not animate.

Comment: @SolomonClosson, you could do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Js7C8/35/