# How to smoothen Collapsible_set in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I created a Collapsible set using jQuery mobile . It is working fine but it is not smooth like Accordion in Jquery UI.
When i tap on header it expands with a jerk.

Is there any way to make it smooth?

Comment: Omar's answer is good. If you also want the option of having more than one collapsible open at a time, look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566967/jquerymobile-1-4-2-animate-collapsible/23568021#23568021 both options are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a `click` listener to collapsible's *heading* `.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle`. Once clicked, `.slideDown()` or `.slideUp()` based on whether the clicked collapsible is collapsed or expanded. When expanding a collapsible, other ones will be collapsed, i.e. only one collapsible should be expanded a time.

```
$(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").on("click", function (e) {
    var current = $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible");
    if (current.hasClass("ui-collapsible-collapsed")) {
        $(".ui-collapsible-content", current).slideDown(300);
        current.siblings(".ui-collapsible:not(.ui-collapsible-collapsed)").find(".ui-collapsible-content").slideUp(300);
    } else {
        $(".ui-collapsible-content", current).slideUp(300);
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/z3fp21m5/)**